# I need to sense if a rope has been touched, what is a safe way to do this?

Tags: sensor, vibration

I was thinking of attaching a sensor to the rope but there are so many types I'm not sure which one to use.

Pizeoelectric, rolling ball, vibration, tilt and tension sensors could all work.

I need the lowest cost, most durable solution. Anyone have any ideas here?

Comment: Can you further describe your application? What is "the rope"? What is the rope connected to?

Comment: Do you mean a rope lying in a pile?  One that's tightly strung between two posts?  Why?

Comment: Sorry, yes a rope strung between two posts. I could add a spring to one side to increase the vibration sensitivity and duration as well. This is for a kids game. They have to maneuver around the ropes, touching one sets off a buzzer.

Comment: Sensitivity and environmental noise needs to be defined; wind, sun, music, shouting, touching the post. Blocking false positives & detection accuracy is what adds cost, which is why I suggested a tiny bell tied to middle of the rope. Sensing is cheap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend an opposed-beam optical sensor.  PCB-mount varieties can be purchased for around $0.25 in low volumes.  Use an extension spring in series with one end of the rope to provide a little compliance (to make it kid proof, keep a length of rope in parallel with the spring so that the spring can only be stretched so far until the rope takes the load).

Use a "flag" or other object attached to the spring to block the sensor when the rope isn't being touched/pulled, and not block the sensor when the spring is stretched a little bit due to rope tension.  You'll need to work out a mechanical solution so that the spring doesn't rotate, which would prevent the flag from returning to its position in the middle of the sensor when the rope isn't being touched.

[image]

Comment: Dean,

How would you adjust the sensitivity? I don't want kids to bump the wall and set off the sensors. I also don't want kids bumping the rope without the sensor going off either.

Thoughts?

Comment: The coarse way to set sensitivity would be to adjust the spring rate.  You'd probably do this once and then settle on a particular spring.  The fine way to set sensitivity would be to adjust the size of the flag or the position of the flag relative to the sensor such that a certain force on the rope is required for the flag to leave the sensor.  This could be accomplished by making the sensor axial position adjustable relative to the spring+flag.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing to use is a proximity sensor. These are commonly used as safety mechanisms on machines. You will need to use thin copper wires instead of a string and isolate them from ground. Anyone touching the wire would cause the system to trip. These are frequently used in security to protect products on shelves.